# Segmentation error through storing object in another class

Tags: c++, matlab, class, mex

I get an segmentation error with the following code in a MATLAB/Simulink c-mex s-function:

```
class Circle
{
public:
    Circle()
    {
        mexPrintf("circle_constructor");
    }

    void draw_circle()
    {
        mexPrintf("circle");
        // code for drawing circle
    }
};

class Master
{
private:
    Circle *member_circle;

public:
    Master()
    {
        member_circle = new Circle();
    }

    void draw()
    {
        member_circle->draw_circle();
    }
};

Master *master_object;
```

In the `mdlStart`-function I use

```
master_object = new Master();
```

and in the `mdlOutputs`-function I use

```
master_object->draw()
```

This last functioncall results in a segmentation violation error. I have posted a relatet question here ([Segmentation fault when calling class from matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814826/segmentation-fault-when-calling-class-from-matlab)), but I figured out that the error somehow occurs every time, when I try to store an object (`Circle`) as property in another class(`Master`).

Do you know how to solve this for MATALB c-mex functions, because the functions works outside MATLAB? Thanks.

Comment: Any class that allocates resources should almost certainly have a copy constructor, an assignment operator and a destructor.

Comment: Try to remove `// code for drawing circle` and see if it still crushes